# Evaluating the importance of Association Rule discovered in R

Tags: r, associations

I am new user to R and i am using it to do Association Analysis for products purchasing data using the library "arules". After i have done the analysis i got a long list of association rules and below are some of them with high lift values:

```
lhs             rhs                Support      Confidence  Lift      
ProdA   =>      ProdB              0.006275139  0.93689005  66.1929547
ProdB   =>      ProdA              0.006275139  0.44334975  66.1929547
ProdC   =>      ProdD              0.009774400  0.68259282  21.8708953
ProdD   =>      ProdC              0.009774400  0.31318068  21.8708953
ProdE   =>      ProdF              0.005516893  0.35631860  10.7673063
ProdF   =>      ProdE              0.005516893  0.16671056  10.7673063
ProdE   =>      ProdB              0.005638909  0.36419927  25.7313287
ProdB   =>      ProdE              0.005638909  0.39839901  25.7313287
```

As i said, i got so many association rules, but i just listed the ones with high values for **Lift**. Now, according to the literature, when the value of **Lift** is 1 or higher, then the association rule is important, which means that the ones listed above are very important. However, when i run the command (is.significant) form "arules" library, i get **false** for all of the rules. I am confused which one to follow! Are they important or not? Could someone help me?

Comment: How did you run `is.significant()`?

Comment: I used the following code line: is.significant(basket_rules, AssociationData). Where basket_rules are the association rules discovered, and the AssociationData is the original data.

Comment: To see if you can get `TRUE` values, play around with `method`, `alpha`, and `adjust`. I would start by increasing `alpha`. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/arules.pdf.  Look at `arules` manual for definitions of `lift` and `is.significant()`. You're right, `lift` indicates dependence, and >1 indicates interdependence. `is.significant()` checks whether the associations in **your data** are statistically significant given the rules determined.